# See complete result of a query and not just the first row

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am making a simple web app. In one part of it, I want PHP to execute a SQL command and send the entire result to JavaScript via AJAX.

This is the code:

```
$meta_query = json_encode(mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT * from meta")));
```

The problem here is that I am only getting the very first row as the result and not the other ones.

I tried:

```
$meta_query = json_encode(mysql_query("SELECT * from meta"));
```

But that's giving me `null`.

What should I do to get the whole result and that too in json format?

Comment: You have lots of problems . . . mysql instead of mysqli or PDO.  Not checking for errors.  Not using a loop.  Look around on Stack Overflow, you'll find lots of examples of the right way to write this type of code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch all rows in a loop:

```
$rows = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from meta");
if($result){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Side note: the MySQL library is deprecated, you should consider upgrading to a modern API such as MySQLi or PDO. PDO has a built in function to get all rows:

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM meta');
$rows = $reuslt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Comment: +1, but i should use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or you will get results with numeric index. Not so explainable.

Comment: OP uses `mysql_fetch_row()` so he wants the numerical indexes not the associative keys. If OP was using mysql_fetch_assoc then you would be absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$meta_query = json_encode(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * from meta")));
```